# neo4y Cypher delete won't commit

Tags: neo4j

I have been experimenting with the REST API recently.  My work cycle involves running my test program which add nodes a relationships to my graphDB, then deleting them by using neo4j-shell with a Cypher command as preparation for the next test run.  All was well until the deletions started failing.  At first I thought this was because my deletions encompassed too many nodes for a single transaction, so I tried to restrict the scope.  It doesn't help.  I'm seeing this...

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (s:Tweeter)-[m:Tweet]->(r:Tweeter) where s.handle =~ '@C.*' delete s,m,r;
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes deleted: 12
Relationships deleted: 21
80 ms
TransactionFailureException: Transaction was marked as successful, but unable to commit transaction so rolled back.
```

I don't know what to try next.  I see no clues in the server log.

Comment: I suspect that my deletions started failing after I increased the complexity of the relations by adding new node types.  By using deletions with more constraints, then following up with the original attempts, I think I am getting past this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem began when I added a second type of target node to the mix with a different label.  I have since change the cleanup to delete all relationships first, then each of the node types.  It's working reliably so far.

Comment: I suppose that I had cases where I tried to delete a "s:Tweeter" node that was related to a "r:Tweeter" and identified by the query, but there were remaining relationship to a "r:Hashtag" node from the same source node that hadn't been identified by the query.  So it couldn't leave the relationship hanging without a source node.  If so, I wish it would have spelled it out more explicitly.

Comment: Duh, yeah.  This works fine: match (s)-[m:Tweet]-(r) delete s,m,r;

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to delete the relationships for the nodes?

```
MATCH
  (s:Tweeter)-[m:Tweet]->(r:Tweeter)
  WHERE s.handle =~ '@C.*'
OPTIONAL MATCH
  s-[orel1]-(),
  r-[orel2]-()
DELETE s,m,r,orel1,orel2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm not familiar with option match, but I'll look into.  In my case, I think the solution is different.  See my answer below.

Comment: `OPTIONAL MATCH` works just like `MATCH` but it will give you a `null` value for any variables that you try to use in a `WITH` or `RETURN` if they don't exist.  I think this would address what you're saying below because this deletes any relationships associated with the `Tweeter` nodes at the same time